# Trying to select item in drop down in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, drop-down-menu, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've been trying to select the sexual orientation from the website here: https://www.okcupid.com/ but I can't seem to get it. I've tried everything from clicking on the element that I want in the drop down with the .Click() method, and then to the support class that's for this (*SelectElement*) like so:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.okcupid.com/");
new SelectElement(driver.FindElementByCssSelector("#orientation_dropdownContainer")).SelectByValue("2");
```

I've tried SelectbyText() as well, and I have tried on different elements (honestly all of them I think) that I could think to use this one and it still stays on the default option, any ideas guys? Using Selenium - Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector seems wrong to me. Use id for the select element `orientation_dropdown`

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.okcupid.com/");
new SelectElement(_driver.FindElement(By.Id("orientation_dropdown"))).SelectByValue("2");
```

**Edit**

This is one of the weirdest select list I have ever seen. However, the code above  will not work and found using `Actions` class can be useful and it will work

```
string option = "Gay";
By xPath = By.XPath("//li[contains(text(),'"+option+"')]");

Actions actions = new Actions(_driver);
actions.MoveToElement(_driver.FindElement(By.Id("orientation_dropdown_chosen"))).Click().Build().Perform();
_driver.FindElement(xPath).Click();
```

Comment: I'll try it when I'm back at my desk, and mark the answer if it works for me :). I do agree though I've worked with Selenium quite a bit and HTML and CSS alot (I'm a webdesigner) so this is one of the oddest ways to do it I've seen. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

- First select the drop down and then select by value or Index-

  `Select drpdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("Locator of the dropdown"));
  drpdown.SelectByValue("Value mentioned in the DOM");`
- If "Earning Report" is a visible Text then

  `drpdown.selectByVisibleText("visible text of the value");`